# Промисы отрабатывают параллельно, а должны последовательно

Tags: javascript, promise

Есть следующий код:

```js
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Promise1 завершен');
        resolve();
    }, 3000)
});
const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Promise2 завершен');
        resolve();
    }, 2000)
});
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Promise3 завершен');
        resolve();
    }, 1000)
});
promise1
    .then(() => promise2)
    .then(() => promise3)
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему вывод в консоль Promise3 завершен, Promise2 завершен, Promise1 завершен. Т.е. все промисы отработали параллельно, а не последовательно
По всей видимости, я не совсем правильно понял механизм работы промисов, раз считаю, что должно произойти следующее:

1. 3 промиса созданы с состоянием pending
2. Обратились к первому промису
3. В первом промисе по истечении 3 секунд поменяли его состояние на fullfiled
4. В первом then отработал колбэк, возвращающий второй промис
   и так далее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция передаваемая в конструктор `Promise` выполняется сразу же, синхронно. Поэтому когда ты создаешь три переменные вначале кода, ты автоматом запускаешь параллельно три таймера.

---

Чтобы это работало как ожидалось, создавать Promise нужно непосредственно в `then`

```js
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Promise1 завершен');
    resolve();
  }, 3000)
});
promise1
  .then(() => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Promise2 завершен');
      resolve();
    }, 2000)
  }))
  .then(() => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Promise3 завершен');
      resolve();
    }, 1000)
  }))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Дополню ответ т-ща @Grundy. Если не хотите, чтобы функция, переданная promise выполнялась сразу же, то можете обернуть промис в функцию, этот промис возвращающую. В таком случае промис начнет выполняться только тогда, когда функция, возвращающая этот промис, будет вызвана.

```js
const promise1 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("1");
        resolve();
    }, 3000)
});

const promise2 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("2");
        resolve();
    }, 2000)
});

const promise3 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
       console.log("3");
        resolve();
    }, 1000)
});

console.log("Start");
promise1()
  .then(() => promise2())
  .then(() => promise3());

// Либо, как подсказал в комментариях тот же Grundy, можно даже так
//
// promise1()
//  .then(promise2)
//  .then(promise3);
```

*Обратите внимание на таймстемпы справа от вывода*

Comment: `.then(() => promise2())` => `.then(promise2)`

Comment: @Grundy справедливо.

Answer (score 1):

Я предлагаю использовать асинхронные функции, так будет понятнее и читабельнее.

Пример реализации:

```
const {promisify} = require('util');
const wait = promisify(setTimeout);

const promise1 = async () => {
    await wait(3000);
    console.log('Promise1 завершен');
}

const promise2 = async () => {
    await wait(2000);
    console.log('Promise2 завершен');
}

const promise3 = async () => {
    await wait(1000);
    console.log('Promise3 завершен');
}

async function callPromises(){
    await promise1()
    await promise2()
    await promise3()
}

callPromises().catch(e=>{console.log(e)});
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас во всех промисах используется функция `SetTimeout`, которая сама по себе уже выполняется асинхронно. Функция передаваемая в конструктор промиса выполняется синхронно (сразу). В промисах 1, 2 и 3 у Вас временные интервалы 3000, 2000 и  1000мс соответственно.

Поэтому вывод в консоль происходит в том порядке, в котором завершаются асинхронные операции.

Передавайте функции вместо конструкторов промисов сразу в `then`.